# Can you insert line breaks into a Rich Text Content Control

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, rtf

I have a rich text content control on a Word 2007 document which is auto-populated from a database query. The control just contains text but ideally I'd like to be able to insert a new line inside the content control so that the text appears like a list. I wrote the SQL query so that it inserted carriage return characters for me, but these are ignored in the content control. I thought I could edit the text in the control when the document appeared - I can add/delete characters and spaces but hitting the 'Enter' button on the keyboard does nothing.

Has anyone found a way to insert line breaks inside the content control?

Answer (score 2):

Switch to design mode, edit the Content Control Properties and select Allow carriage returns (multiple paragraphs).

Comment: This option is available in the plain text control but, if you use a rich text control then, that option is not available.  I am linking the information using XML tools and it doesn't look like I can use the plain text control.

Answer (score 0):

When editing a rich text content control manually, hitting Shift+Enter inserts a new line. Can you provide more details on how you are populating your content control?

Comment: Shift+Enter doesn't work for me. I thought I had tried that and Ctrl+Enter but nothing seems to add a line break. I can edit it with text characters and spaces. Populating the content control is done with a database call which does a FOR XML to provide the data in xml format. I used the Word 2007 Content Control Toolkit download: http://dbe.codeplex.com/releases/view/695 to map the content controls to xml nodes. The data in the xml node then gets substituted automatically into the content control. Mike Ormonds blog is very good: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2006/08/17/704579.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Word 2010 RichText control supports newlines. Word 2007 and Word 2016 do not support RichText control multiline.

Comment: Do you have reference to support this?